# Best way to fill in gaps between dates in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that tracks customer status changes over time but only on the date the status change occurred. I am trying to create a table that tracks the status daily, currently my table looks like this

| ID | logdate | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-07-06 | active |
| 123 | 2021-11-12 | inactive |
| 123 | 2022-05-20 | active |

What I am trying to achieve is to fill in the gaps, so that from 2021-07-06 I have a row for each date with the customer status up until it changes, and so on. Something like:

| ID | logdate | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-07-06 | active |
| 123 | 2021-07-07 | active |
| 123 | 2021-07-08 | active |
| ... | .... | ... |
| 123 | 2021-11-11 | active |
| 123 | 2021-11-12 | inactive |
| 123 | 2021-11-13 | inactive |
| ... | .... | ... |
| 123 | 2022-05-19 | inactive |
| 123 | 2022-05-20 | active |
| 123 | 2022-05-21 | active |

Appreciate any input on the best way to achieve this

I have a date dimension and tried a cross join but I am struggling with the multiple status changes over time

Comment: Please show what your DateDimension table looks like. Do you have a StatusDimension table also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First construct a start/end date for each existing record using lag/lead:

```
SELECT id, logdate, LEAD(logdate) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY logdate) as endlogdate, status 
FROM yourtable;
```

With that result set/derived table you can join to your date dimension table:

```
SELECT yt.id, dd.datefield, yt.status
FROM datedimension AS dd
    INNER JOIN 
        (
             SELECT id, logdate, DATEADD(DAY, -1, LEAD(logdate) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY logdate)) as endlogdate, status 
             FROM yourtable
        ) AS yt
        ON dd.datefield BETWEEN yt.logdate and yt.endlogdate
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `generate_series` :

```
with cte as (
  select *, lead(logdate, 1, DATEADD(day, 10, logdate)) over (partition by ID order by logdate) as leaddate
  from mytable
)
SELECT ID, status, DATEADD(DAY, dd.value - 1, logdate) as new_logdate
FROM cte
cross join generate_series( 1, 
                            (SELECT max(DATEDIFF(day, logdate, leaddate)) FROM cte), 
                          1) dd
where DATEADD(DAY, dd.value, logdate) <= leaddate
order by new_logdate
```

First Cte used to get next date, if not exists ( last date) get a specific date of your choice, by changing the parameter of the `lead(logdate, 1, DATEADD(day, 10, logdate))`, 10 means the 10th day after the selected day.

The maximum difference between the logdate and the next date is the stop parameter for the `generate_series` function, which has three inputs: start, stop, and step.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-yTjdLRp)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I am unable to use generate_series due to the compatibility level of my db which I am currently unable to change

Comment: There are a number of well tested date range functions available. eg: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/a-daterange-table-valued-function

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cte and window function without Date Dimension . First, this is code calculate the end date. If there is no end date, then fill the gap with logdate.

```
with a as (
select *,DATEADD(day,-1, LEAD(logdate,1,logdate) over(partition by ID  order by logdate)) enddate
from ttt
), dates_CTE  as (
    select ID,status,logdate as org,logdate,enddate
    from a
    Union ALL
    select bb.ID,bb.status,o.logdate as org,DATEADD(day, 1, bb.logdate) as date,o.enddate
    from dates_CTE bb
    inner join a o on o.logdate=bb.org and bb.ID = o.ID and bb.status = o.status
    where   bb.logdate < o.enddate
)
select ID,status,logdate
from dates_CTE
order by id,logdate
option (maxrecursion 0)
```